# Cannot upload sketch to DFRduino nano

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, atmega328, softwareserial

I previously succeed in uploading the code to DFRDuino Nano (Arduino Nano Compatible) (with wrong digital pins) but after changing pin I cannot upload it again.

From the [document](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Arduino_Nano_328__SKU__DFR0010_), I changed back the pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX) are used for serial communication.

In arduino ide (1.8.19), I choosed **board: Arduino Nano** and **Processor: ATmega328P(Old Bootloader)**

The error:

```
. . .

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

        Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

        Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch


        System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.57.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

        Using Port                    : COM3

        Using Programmer              : arduino

        Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00


avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I have reset both the board and computer but without luck. I changed another board and got the same error.

Any idea how to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

I uploaded the empty code to reset the board but it yielded the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by "uploading with wrong digital pins" and with "changed back the pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX)"? On the Nano you cannot choose the pins of the Hardware Serial interface. They are literally hardwired

Comment: @chrisl I mean at first I used other digital pins for serial communication (d11 d12) using SerialSoftware and did not notice that d0 d1 are hardwired and used for serial com.

Comment: What you are doing with SoftwareSerial in your sketch doesn't matter for the bootloader (which is handling the upload). Have you tried resetting the board right after you clicked on upload? It might take some tries to get the timimg right

Comment: Assuming "_I changed another board and got the same error._" means that you tried with another Arduino. Then the problem is on your PC. Did you select the right board and port?

Comment: @thebusybee I changed other DFRduino. I selected Arduino Nano and right COM since it was the only one)

Comment: Does the Hardware Manager show the DFRDuino? Did you double-check any connection, and that the correct Nano (there are several of them) is selected as the linked page suggests?

Comment: @thebusybee I cannot see any DFRDuino from Boards Manager. From the document (above) in **programming** section, it states `The DFRduino Nano can be programmed with the DFRduino software (download)...Nano w/ ATmega328P(Old Bootloader)" from the Tools > Board menu`

Comment: I did not mean the Board Manager in the IDE. I meant the Hardware Manager of your PC, presumed that you use Windows (any other reasonable OS will have something similar).

Comment: @thebusybee it does not show any DfRDuino at all

Comment: Then you need to debug the USB connection. Try other USB devices, other Arduinos, other USB cables, other USB ports, ...